# How to import parameters of a different class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have two files cointoss and flibbell, python programs. I have to import cointoss into flibbell so that flibbell can inherit the number of flips given by the user. The flibbell will then stimulate multiple cointosses in a tkinter GUI. The cointoss file must have a main() so when I tried to run cointoss without `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it works but when I run the cointoss file using CoinToss() which is the class, it gives me error saying `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'flips'`

When I then try to run flipbell.py with cointoss inherited, it gives me an error saying it does not recognize the CoinToss **init** variable.

Here is the cointoss file:

```
    from random import randint
    import random


    class CoinToss:
        def __init__(self,flips):

            self.state = 1
            self.numb = flips

        def __str__(self):
            firstline = 'The ball at the start : ball: %d, state : %d, value : %d' % (0,0,self.numb)
            return firstline





        def flip(self):
            rand_value = randint(0, 1)
            if rand_value == 1:
                self +=1
            else:
                self -=1
            return self

    def main():
        flips = int(input("give the number of flips: "))
        dxp = CoinToss(flips)
        print(dxp)
        k = 0
        value_change = flips

        for i in range(1,(flips*2) +1):
            flips = value_change
            value_change = CoinToss.flip(flips)
            print('after: ball: %d, state: %d, value: %d' % (i, k , value_change))
            k = k+1


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

When I run the cointoss file alone, this is the result I am supposed to get:

```
python cointoss.py
Give the number of flips : 6
The ball at the start : ball : 0, state : 0, value : 3
after flip 1, ball : 0, state : 1, value : 2
after flip 2, ball : 0, state : 2, value : 3
after flip 3, ball : 0, state : 3, value : 2
after flip 4, ball : 0, state : 4, value : 3
after flip 5, ball : 0, state : 5, value : 2
after flip 6, ball : 0, state : 6, value : 1
```

And here is the flipbell file:

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, W, E
    import random
    from RRcointossRR import *



    class FlipBell(CoinToss):
        """
        GUI to simulate billiard ball movement.
        """
        def __init__(self, wdw, increment, delay):
            super(FlipBell,self).__init__(num_flip)
            """
            Determines the layout of the GUI.
            wdw : top level widget, the main window,
            dimension : determines the size of the canvas,
            increment : step size for a billiard move,
            delay : time between updates of canvas.
            """
            self.ballList = []
            wdw.title('Coin flips and Bell Curve')
            self.dim = num_flip # dimension of the canvas
            self.inc = increment
            self.dly = delay
            self.togo = False # state of animation
            # initial coordinates of the ball
            self.xpt = self.dim//2
            self.ypt = 0
            self.cnv = Canvas(wdw, width=self.dim,\
                height=self.dim, bg='white')
            self.cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
            self.bt0 = Button(wdw, text='start',\
                command=self.start)
            self.bt0.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.bt1 = Button(wdw, text='stop',\
                command=self.stop)
            self.bt1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)
            self.points = {}
            self.end_points = {}
            self.value = 0


        def placecoin(self, xpt, ypt):
            self.cnv.create_oval(xpt-1, ypt-1, xpt+1, ypt+1,\
                width=2, outline='red', fill='red', tags='coin')

        def drawball(self,ball):
            """
            Draws the ball on the canvas.
            """
            ball.x = ball.value[1][self.points[ball]]
            ball.y += ball.dy
            self.cnv.create_oval(ball.x-1, ball.y-1, ball.x+1, ball.y+1,\
                width=1, outline='black', fill='red', tags='dot')
            if ball.y == self.dim:
                print(ball.x)
                print(ball.y)
                if self.end_points[ball.x]>=1:
                    print("inside 1")
                    self.placecoin(ball.x,ball.y-self.end_points[ball.x])
                else:
                    self.placecoin(ball.x,ball.y)
                self.end_points[ball.x]+=2
                self.ypt = 0


        def add(self): # Add a new ball
            a=Ball(self.dim)
            self.ballList.append(a)
            self.points[a] = 0


        def animate(self):
            """
            Performs the animation.
            """
            for i in range(1,(self.dim)+1):
                self.end_points[i] = 0
            while self.togo:
                self.add()
                self.cnv.delete('dot')

                self.value+=1

                for ball in self.ballList:
                    self.drawball(ball)
                    self.points[ball]+=1
                    if self.points[ball] == self.dim:
                        self.ballList.remove(ball)
                        self.value = 0
                self.cnv.update()


        def start(self):
            """
            Starts the animation.
            """
            self.togo = True
            self.animate()

        def stop(self):
            """
            Stops the animation.
            """
            self.togo = False
    class Ball(FlipBell):
        ball = 0
        def __init__(self, dimension):
            self.dim = dimension
            self.x = (self.dim)//2 # Starting center position
            self.y = 0
            self.dx = 10 # Move right by default
            self.dy = 1# Move down by defaultaa
            self.value = CoinToss.main()
            Ball.ball += 1

    def main():
        """
        Defines the dimensions of the canvas
        and launches the main event loop.
        """
        top = Tk()
         # dimension of canvas
        increment = 10  # increment for coordinates
        delay = 1      # how much sleep before update
        num_flips = 3
        num_value = dimension//2
        FlipBell(top, increment, delay)
        top.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Also, I need to change **value** in **self.value = CoinToss()** located in Class Ball(FlipBell): according to the CoinToss main, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: For starters, I see num\_flip isn't being passed into FlipBell(), so when \_\_init\_\_ is run, it's not going to know what "num\_flip" is referring to.

Comment: But doesn't it get passed with the "super()" method??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, because `num_flip` isn't defined globally (which it shouldn't be), your `super()` method can't find any variable called `num_flip`.  This number needs to be passed into the subclass's `__init__`, and then passed to the parent class.  See:

```
class FlipBell(CoinToss):
    """
    GUI to simulate billiard ball movement.
    """
    def __init__(self, wdw, increment, delay, num_flip):
        super(FlipBell,self).__init__(num_flip)
```

or more commonly and generally:

```
class FlipBell(CoinToss):
    """
    GUI to simulate billiard ball movement.
    """
    def __init__(self, wdw, increment, delay, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FlipBell,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```